# How to use tree without listing contents of .app file in Mac

Tags: macos, terminal

I am using `tree` to list contents of a folder. I have many macOS apps with `.app` extension. I want tree to list them but ignore the contents inside it. How to do that? Thanks.

Comment: tree is a plain POSIX command so does not know about macOS bundles. You'll need a macOS specific tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tree` has `-P` and `-I` to show/hide files based on wild-card patterns but I didn't have any luck so far using them to hide the content of specific directories.

You can remove the content of `NAME.app` directories with `grep` though:

```bash
tree -f | grep -v '\.app/'
```

`-f` is required in this case to allow filtering on the whole path.

If you don't want to see the whole path, you can also remove it again with `sed`:

```bash
tree -f | grep -v '\.app/' | sed 's| \./.*/||'
```

The resulting output is similar to the one you get without `-f`, but without the content of the `.app` directories.

Comment: Thanks. Works. But I don't want the full path prefix for each file listed. I guess I will just remove the app content entries manually.

Comment: @JohnDoe Found a way to remove the path after the filtering. Not sure it covers all edge cases.

Comment: I did not get time to test it. I will update when I do. Thank you!